# When do I need shim and when do I need sham?

Tags: es5-shim

Why does the [EC5 Shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) library have two files? When do I need each one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shim vs. Sham: What is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508833/shim-vs-sham-what-is-the-difference)